# UART Rx TX pins not reading sensor output RPI3

Tags: gpio, sensor, uart

This is my first pi project so I'm a bit new at this. I'm trying to connect a senseair K-30 CO2 sensor to the pi via the UART gpio pins. This is the sensor I am using: https://www.co2meter.com/products/k-30-co2-sensor-module

and I set it up following the app note here: http://www.co2meters.com/Documentation/AppNotes/AN137-K30-sensor-raspberry-pi-uart.pdf

I have done some changes to try to get it to work in python3

However, the co2 comes up with a error message. If I use /dev/ttyS0 I get the error message. Traceback (most recent call last):   File "K-30_3.py", line 18, in    high = ord(resp[3])  IndexError: index out of range.  But if I use /dev/ttyAMA0 it seems to do nothing.

What I've done so far:

- Went into `raspi-config` and under interfacing options, changed "Would you like a login shell to be accessible over serial?" to "No" and "Would you like the serial port hardware to be enabled" to "Yes"
- Added the line `enable_uart=1` and `dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt` to the `/boot/config.txt` file.
- Deleted the line `console=/dev/ttyS0,115200` in the `/boot/cmdline.txt` file.
- Did both `systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyS0.service` and `systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyS0.service`.

I'm still a little confused and any help would be much appreciated!

Here is what the sensor uses:

```
#rpi serial connections
#Python app to run a K-30 Sensor
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0",baudrate =9600,timeout = .5)
print ("  AN-137: Raspberryu Pi3 to K-30 Via UART\n")
ser.flushInput()
time.sleep(1,21)

for i in range(1):

    ser.flushInput()
    ser.write(b"\xFE\x44\x00\x08\x02\x9F\x25")
    time.sleep(.5)
    resp = ser.read(7)
    high = ord(resp[3])
    low = ord(resp[4])
    co2 = (high*256) + low
    print ("i = ",i, " CO2 = " +str(co2))
    time.sleep(.1)
```

And the output:

```
  AN- 137: Raspberry Pi3 to K-30 via UART

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K-30_3.py", line 18, in <module>
    high = ord(resp[3])
IndexError: index out of range
```

However, if I change ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0",baudrate =9600,timeout = .5) to ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",baudrate =9600,timeout = .5)

The output is this:

```
  AN- 137: Raspberry Pi3 to K-30 via UART
```

It is either doing nothing or is hanging.

I'm using `Python 3.7` on Raspberry Pi OS Codename `Buster`.

Comment: It is difficult to understand WHY you would have done this or what OS you are using. Try a fresh install and **don't fiddle with boot files**.

Comment: I'm using 'Python 3.7' on Raspberry Pi OS Codename 'Buster'.

Answer (score 1):

Start again with a fresh install.

1. Use `raspi-config` to enable serial.
2. Use `/dev/serial0` in your script.

Comment: I have done a fresh install and what you have suggested. However I still get the same results. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Please edit your post and show the software listing you are using.

Comment: @Marc All relevant information should be edited into your question.